# Req,File.Path remains undefined and i am using multer due to vague documentation,i cannot fully understant it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I,m using mutler to upload a image and i am constantly getting this error.

[image: Error]
And i think the following function triggers it.
The complete js code is attached below.Thanks in advance!

```
const upload = multer({
  dest: "/uploads"
});


app.post(
  "/game",
  upload.single("file" /* name attribute of <file> element in your form */),
  (req, res) => {
    const tempPath = req.file.Path;
    const targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "/uploads/"+imgname+".jpg");
    imgname++;

    if (path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase() === ".jpg") {
      fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, err => {
        if (err) return handleError(err, res);

        res
          .status(200)
          .sendFile(__dirname + '/game.html');

      });
    } else {
      fs.unlink(tempPath, err => {
        if (err) return handleError(err, res);

        res
          .status(403)
          .contentType("text/plain")
          .end("Only .jpg files are allowed!");
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Js file link: https://filebin.net/fd7q89ji16xftst4

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have a variable called `imgname`. After checking the code, it looks like you need to pass the file name for the `imgname`. You can use `req.file.filename` to get the name of the uploaded file.

Full code:

```
const upload = multer({
  dest: "/uploads"
});


app.post(
  "/game",
  upload.single("file" /* name attribute of <file> element in your form */),
  (req, res) => {
    const tempPath = req.file.Path;
    const imgname = req.file.filename;
    const targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "/uploads/"+imgname);
    imgname++;

    if (path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase() === ".jpg") {
      fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, err => {
        if (err) return handleError(err, res);

        res
          .status(200)
          .sendFile(__dirname + '/game.html');

      });
    } else {
      fs.unlink(tempPath, err => {
        if (err) return handleError(err, res);

        res
          .status(403)
          .contentType("text/plain")
          .end("Only .jpg files are allowed!");
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried to do as suggested by you but then this(given above) occured.

Comment: plus you used the made imgname const, which i have to increment but when i try to change its datatype to let, again error occurs